# How do I pass jQuery data to a usercontrol?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, user-controls, accordion

I have a list of projects set out in a jQuery accordion.

I also have a custom user control that the user enters information about that project. (Just some dropdowns, a text box, and a submit button.) When the user clicks to add info, the control pops up via a colorbox.

```
  <a class="colorBoxLink" href="javascript:void(0);">Add Info</a>
<asp:Repeater ID="rptProjectList" OnItemDataBound="rptProjects_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <div id="accordion">
    </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>

        <h1 style="margin: 0px" class="accordionHeader" id='P<%# Eval("projectCode") %>'>
            <asp:Label ID="lblProjCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("projectCode") %>'></asp:Label>
            - <%# Eval("title") %>
            <p style="color: red; margin: 0px">Deadline: <%# Eval("deadline", "{0:d MMM yy}") %> ECD: <%# Eval("ecd", "{0:d MMM yy}") %></p>
        </h1>

        <div>


            <asp:Repeater ID="rptCompletedProjectTasks" OnItemDataBound="rptCompletedProjectTasks_ItemDataBound" runat="server">

                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <h3>Completed Tasks</h3>
                    <table class="projTaskTable">
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width: 100px">W/C</th>
                            <th style="width: 450px">Description</th>
                            <th style="width: 100px">Due</th>
                            <th style="width: 100px">Completed</th>
                            <th style="width: 50px">Var</th>
                        </tr>
                </HeaderTemplate>

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="tdWeek" runat="server">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblWeek" runat="server" Text='x'></asp:Label></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("description") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("deadline", "{0:d MMM}") %></td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCompleted" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("completedDate", "{0:d MMM}") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("var") %></td>

                    </tr>

                </ItemTemplate>

                <FooterTemplate></table></FooterTemplate>

            </asp:Repeater>


        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <FooterTemplate>
        </div>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>




<div id="popup" style="display: none; height: 320px">
    <uc1:TaskCreator runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" ProjectCode="X" ID="TaskCreator" />
</div>
```

I need to be able to pass the currently selected index of the accordion to the user-control. (i.e. user clicks on header for Project XYZ, clicks on Add to pop up the usercontrol, and then when user submits the form on the control, I need it to "know" that project XYZ was selected as this will be the project it updates.)

Comment: It would really help to see the rendered html (run the app and view the page source).

Comment: .... and the javascript.